# No Nontrivial Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension $n \geq 2$.  Suppose $A$ $\in L(V, V)$ is a nonzero transformations such that for each subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $AW \subset W$ we have $W = 0$ or $W = V$.

Question:  What should it tell me about A when the only invariant subspaces under A are trivial?  Is there a useful theorem I'm not familiar with that I could look up to understand this better?

Comment: What is the role of the two linear transformations? It seems that the question you're asking is really just about a single linear transformation (unless I'm missing something). In any case, your question is related to the eigenvalues of the matrix, and to its Jordan canonical form....

Comment: (1) What exactly is your Q? (2) Do you mean a vector space over $R$ or a vector subspace of $R^n$?

Comment: This can only happen when $n$ is even because every real polynomial of odd degree has a root and so every linear transformation on a vector space of odd dimension has an eigenvalue.